# React Native Images disappearing when returning from background

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The title kind of says it all. When returning to my React Native app after it's been running in the background for a while, all (or at least some) Image element pointing to external `uri`s will go blank.

Thinking that's it might be iOS taking the app's memory away, I've tried to make the app rerender - and reload those images - when it becomes active with:

```
React.AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', (newState) => {
    if(newState === "active") {
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
});
```

But while it does rerender, it doesn't reload the images.

What's going on here?

Comment: I handled this issue by assigning a variable to Flex value of it's style. It solved the issue on iOS. I didn't have the issue on Android anyway.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy what do you mean by assigning flex value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue specifically with GIFs. It looks like this is a bug with `React Native` as reported here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4606

I hacked up a workaround where I am storing the `AppState`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    appState: 'active'
  };
  AppState.addEventListener('change', newState => this.setState({ appState: newState }));
}
```

And then I only render the image with the correct `source` when the `AppState` is `active` so that when it goes into `inactive` or `background` the `Image` is blank and is forced to rerender when moving back into `active`:

```
render() {
  return <Image source={{ uri: this.state.appState === 'active' ? this.props.imageUrl : '' }} />;
}
```

The actual code I'm using is a bit different since I'm using `redux` to handle my app state but this should work the same.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks again.